# Hyperlink authenticated acces through R shiny

Tags: r, url, shiny, data-science, business-intelligence

I want to to create a URL using R shiny. The objective  is to create a URL that runs a basic request response process requests an updated report file from a server with authentication details and the server in response if authentication details or token is correct replies with acknowledgment and  the file is automatically invoked (for exmaple : executing a dataset url on jupyter notebook). What will  be the procedure to create such a URL in R shiny, even if I could get like a flow or algorithm, would be great. Thank you !!

I tried different methods for hyper link and applied different authentication techniques (didn't work)

Comment: When you say "create a URL", are you talking about hosting a [`shiny`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) app or a [`plumber`](https://www.rplumber.io) API? If the user needs to authenticate to the app, that's either an issue for shiny-server or posit-connect, or something like [`shinymanager`](https://github.com/datastorm-open/shinymanager) (I know nothing about that).

Comment: A plumber API, no need to run an app

Comment: https://gabrielcp.medium.com/using-firebase-for-authentication-in-an-r-plumber-application-an-example-with-angular-c7f611b6fb56 is an option

Comment: There are a few components to this question: (1) how to set up an API endpoint (e.g., `plumber`) _in general_; (2) how to incorporate part or all of a jupyter notebook into the calcs and/or results; and (3) how to require users authenticate before using this endpoint. I believe the first is sufficiently (if not exhaustively) documented at https://www.rplumber.io; the second is outside of my knowledge, I tend to use "just R" and/or Rmd docs using `rmarkdown::render`; and the third is much more difficult to implement from scratch, see the blog post in my previous comment.

Comment: I suggest you solve #1 on your own, "playing" with plumber in its examples and documentation, I don't think SO is the right way to try to accelerate initial learning. #2 by itself can be applicable as a stand-alone question on SO, though make sure to provide a reproducible question by adding both the plumber endpoint and a sample jupyter notebook with a simple and unambiguous expected output. Once you have all of that working, you'll need to decide on where it is being hosted, as the hosting platform might answer authentication automatically (i.e., on Posit Connect) or sway how you can do it.